# Alias not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

First to confirm, aliases ARE working. this is strange issue with just few aliases that are not working.

I created a page (on my local machine right now so no link), with URL alias of "donate". But whenever I try to access this page http://www.example.com/donate, it just loads (not redirects) home page.

If I change the alias to, say, "donate1" (or something) then it works. It loads the proper donate page.

I even checked the database but can't find where "donate" might be pointing to home page.

Can some one please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the admin page go to url-aliases in site building section. You will find all your aliases.